# cmake - add .so library with it's .h headers

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with structure like this:

```
project/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main.cpp
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ lib/
│  ├─ libapi.so
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ dep/
│  ├─ api/
│  │  ├─ api_types.h
```

In the main CMakeLists I have:

```
add_subdirectory(dep)
add_executable("my_${PROJECT_NAME}")
add_subdirectory(src)
```

And in CMakeLists inside `src` folder:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_library(api SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET api PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libapi.so")
target_sources("my_${PROJECT_NAME}" PRIVATE main.cpp)
```

In main.cpp I do `#include <api_types.h>` but I get this error during compile:
`api_types.h: No such file or directory`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First - `add_subdirectory` in fact just looks for `CMakeLists.txt` in
  the specified directory to apply the sub-set of the rules to the
  parent project. If the specified folder doesn't contain any
  `CMakeLists.txt` this command does nothing (i.e. the command
  `add_subdirectory(dep)`).
- Second - `target_include_directories` expects a **target** object to link against (not the project name). Assuming `${PROJECT_NAME}` is not a name of any of your targets (and the code given in the question reveals only two targets `my_${PROJECT_NAME}` and `api`) the command `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` does nothing sensible.
- Last - you don't specify path to your actual headers anywhere. `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` refers to the current folder **CMakeLists.txt** is located in. You should specify path to the folder the headers are located in.

Putting all the said info together, the desired content for the top-level CMakeLists.txt should be something like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(PROJECT_NAME Hello)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(my_${PROJECT_NAME})
add_subdirectory(src)
```

And for src's file it's apparently something like that:

```
target_include_directories(my_${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/api)

target_sources(my_${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE main.cpp)
```

---

This solution, however, doesn't resolve another mistake in your code - the CMake files you provided don't link the library itself to the executable target. However this is not the question asked, and with respect to the members of the community, I suggest referring to answers to another related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library).

Comment: 1. I still get `api_types.h: No such file or directory`  
2. Doesn't this part link the library? `add_library(api SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET api PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libapi.so")`

Comment: @Dmitry you link library with `target_link_library`, while `add_library` just adds the library target (not linked to anything). For the first issue i can't see why exactly this could be happening, but let me quickly implement this solution locally and check if it works

Comment: @Dmitry my bad, i just used `include` instead of `dep` folder. Just ensure that `target_include_directories` refers to actual folder in your project. Now it should be good

Comment: Still don't get it =( Can this part be wrong? `#include <api_types.h>`

Comment: Found the typo. Stupid me >.<

Answer (score 0):

`target_include_directories` requires your executable as target, in this case `my_${PROJECT_NAME}`.

You can try

```
target_include_directories(my_${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

As alternative I would recommend following structure

```
project/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main.cpp
├─ lib/
│  ├─ libapi.so
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ include/
│  ├─ api/
│  │  ├─ api_types.h
```

with following CMakeList.txt

```
add_executable(my_${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(my_${PROJECT_NAME} libapi)
```